# Distributing jar files properly

Tags: file, jar

So I compiled my project as a .jar in NetBeans. The jar file runs flawlessly when running on any machine with NetBeans installed, but refuses to run on a NetBeans-free machine. I'm writing this software to distribute to people that probably aren't Java programmers so this is an issue. I read that I might need to convert it to an exe file? If so how do I make one? And if thats not the solution what is?I just couldn't find something that explained this well enough, so I thought I should post it here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to run the application?

To run a jar you need to type "java -jar [myfilename.jar]". You can, of cozurse, make a .bat file to do this for the user.